# How to simplify this expression using tensor notaion?

Tags: notation, vector-analysis, tensors

$\nabla^2 (\phi A)-A \nabla^2 \phi -2(\nabla \phi \cdot\nabla)A$

Where $A,\phi$ are any sufficiently smooth vector and scalar fields respectively.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$\nabla^2 (\phi \vec A)=\partial_i^2(\phi A_j)=\phi \partial_i^2(A_j)+2\partial_i (\phi) \partial_i(A_j)+A_j\partial_i^2(\phi)=\phi \nabla^2 \vec A+2(\nabla \phi \cdot \nabla)\vec A+\vec A \nabla^2 \phi$

And the rest is trivial.

Comment: can i ask why $\partial_i(\phi)\partial_i(A_i)=(\nabla\phi \cdot \nabla)A$

Comment: i thought $\partial_j(\phi)\partial_j(A_i)=(\nabla\phi \cdot \nabla)A$

Comment: Yes, you are correct.